# Set table Name and property dynamically ,base on Condition(DBContext)

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext

my below code is worked Properly but i want to reduce the line of code by replacing static table name and its property `join dr in DBContext.tblExHits on uI.ImageId equals dr.ImageId into drLikes` of code dynamically, below i achived this task using sql query and pass table name there that works well,but this thime i'm using LINQ mention above

1.

```
var tblname = typeof(T).Name.ToUpper();
var query = "Select * From " + tblname + " where DeviceId ='" + DeviceId + "' and ImageId='" + ImageId + "'  ";
```

2. here is my Proper Code

```
case 1:
var    getresult = (from uI in DBContext.tblUrlImage
         join dr in DBContext.tblExHits on uI.ImageId equals dr.ImageId into drLikes
         from dr in drLikes.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where uI.CategoryId == CategoryId
         group dr by new { uI.ImageId, uI.ImageName,  
                           uI.ImageUrl3x, uI.CreatedOn, uI.CategoryId } into grouped
         orderby grouped.Key.CreatedOn descending
         select new UrlImageVM
         {
           ImageId = grouped.Key.ImageId,
           ImageName = grouped.Key.ImageName,
           ImageUrl3x = grouped.Key.ImageUrl3x,
           CategoryId = grouped.Key.CategoryId,
           CreatedOn = grouped.Key.CreatedOn,
           TotalLikes = grouped.Count(imgid =>imgid.ImageId != null)
         }).Skip((Page - 1) * 5).Take(5);                                                   
var lst = getresult.ToList();`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
IQueryable<UrlImages> src;
switch(something) {
  case 1: src=db.Table1.AsQueryable(); break;
  case 2: src=db.Table2.AsQueryable(); break;
  ...
}
var result=src
  .Where(i=>i.DeviceId==deviceId)
  .GroupBy(...)
  .OrderBy(...)
  .Skip(...)
  .Take(...);
```